# Intercept file upload submit using jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

I have a .net mvc application that allows users to submit an attachment. For this, I am not using anything special such as plugins, etc, just using a standard form post.

However, I'd like to intercept the request with a confirmation dialog, and only post on OK.

In order to do so, I am using preventDefault, otherwise the the dialog box only appears for a second, and then the form posts.

Seems pretty straight forward. The problem I'm running into is that because it's a file upload, I need to continue submission and essentially undo the preventDefault.

So the problem I am running into is that I have to use preventDefault in order to stop the standard submission, but it also stops submission completely upon the user selecting OK to continue. Again, because of the file upload, I have to allow default behavior, because trying to do it any other way, i.e. $.post('@Url.Action("etc", "etc")', $('#form').serialize());, will then cause the controller to not receive the uploaded file.

Here is my code thus far:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {

        var evt = e || event;
        if (evt.preventDefault)
            evt.preventDefault();
        else
            evt.returnValue = false;

        $('#divConfirm').dialog({
            height: 200,
            width: 450,
            title: 'Confirm',
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                    //$.post('@Url.Action("etc", "etc")', $('#form').serialize());
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    //evt.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
        $('#divConfirm').dialog("open");
    });
});
```

So preventDefault stops all submision even on acceptance, but removing it prevents the dialog completely, only flashing the dialog box for a second. I have searched similar posts, but not found any solutions yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of doing it on the submit why not call the dialog and use the OK side of the dialog to perform the functionality that the submit would?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {

    var evt = e || event;
    if (evt.preventDefault)
        evt.preventDefault();
    else
        evt.returnValue = false;

    var formElement = this; //****modified***
    $('#divConfirm').dialog({
        height: 200,
        width: 450,
        title: 'Confirm',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                 formElement.submit(); //****modified***
                return true;
                //$.post('@Url.Action("etc", "etc")', $('#form').serialize());
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                //evt.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```